# How to bind the page title to the datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I need to bind title to the datasource so the web page title will show depends on the data in datasource.

When i'm using the Formview and the hiddenfield to get the data from datasource the code cannot compile

How to create a script that the pagetitle can be display based on the data in datasource?

```
<Script runat = "server">
 Protected sub Page_load(Byval sender as Object, Byval e As System.eventargs)
     Title = Hiddenfield1.value
 End sub
</Script>

<asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

<ItemTemplate>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value= '<%#eval ("PageTitleConstruct") %>' />

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  Sub FormView2_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim HiddenField1 As HiddenField = CType(FormView2.FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)

    Page.Title = HiddenField1.Value;

  End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried the script, but when using the

Sub FormView2_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim HiddenField1 As HiddenField = CType(FormView2.FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)

    Page.Title = HiddenField1.Value;

End Sub

The page.title value only nothing

But correct if i change the Event to 

  Private Sub FormView2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView2.Load
        Dim hiddenfield1 As HiddenField = CType(FormView2.FindControl("hiddenfield1"), HiddenField)     
        Page.Title = hiddenfield1.Value
  End Sub

Answer (score 0):

In the Page_Load function. You'll have to get the value earlier than you are though.

```
 Page.Title = value here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to listen for the [`ItemCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcreated.aspx) event, and set the title in that callback.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the script, but when using the

```
FormView2_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim HiddenField1 As HiddenField = CType(FormView2.FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)

    Page.Title = HiddenField1.Value;

End Sub
```

The page.title value only nothing

But correct if i change the Event to

```
Private Sub FormView2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView2.Load
        Dim hiddenfield1 As HiddenField = CType(FormView2.FindControl("hiddenfield1"), HiddenField)     
        Page.Title = hiddenfield1.Value
  End Sub
```